# How to import data as qualified?

Tags: purescript

I have the following declaration:

```
data Route
  = Home
  | SignUp
  | LogIn
  | NotFound
```

I know I can import it like `import App.Routes (Route(..))` and use it like  `route.navigate Home` for example.

But how is the appropiate way to use it with qualified access?

```
import App.Routes (Route)
-- ...
 route.navigate Route.Home
```

throws: `Unknown module Route`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import a module qualified, use the `as` keyword:

```
import App.Routes as Route
```

If you want to further limit the set of stuff accessible via dot, you can add the parens too:

```
import App.Routes (Route(..)) as Route
```

Further, you can import multiple modules this way, and they all will be accessible with the same qualifier:

```
import App.Routes (Route(..)) as Route
import App.Navigation (navigate) as Route

...

Route.navigate Route.Home
```

But in this case you better keep the parens on both imports, otherwise the compiler will give you a warning about potential name conflicts.

---

Separately, even if you're not importing qualified, I strongly recommend still explicitly listing all the imports:

```
import App.Routes (Route(..))
```

This will make it much easier to make sense of your program in a few months, when you have forgotten all about it.

Comment: increible expresability